# Excel: Delete everything after the first word in every row

Tags: excel

I have a list of first names and last names (in a column) in excel. Each row has a first and its corresponding last name.
I would like to get only the first names.

ex.

```
original data: james smith
output: james
```

Is there a formula for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Comment: I tend to find myself wrapping `TRIM()` in this exact formula.  Is that overkill, or could you see a time where it'd be good to use? (I suppose it's only advantage would be if the original string had *leading* spaces?)

Comment: @BruceWayne If the string had leading spaces, you wouldn't want to wrap `Trim()` around the result - you would want to trim first. I could see its use in that instance, but no so much in the other.

Comment: But then again - I am known to overkill some strings on occasion myself. Overkill is better than not killing at all imo.